# Remove Words From A DF that appear in another DF (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Right now, I have a DF1 like this:

```
 Words              Words1                Words2  
 Shell Shocked      Big Bang Theory       Hot Potato 
 Falling Down       Tiger Blood           Blue Suede Shoe 
 A Big Window       Mouse Trap
 Look Around
```

**What I was hoping to do was do some sort of vlookup equivalent and remove all words that appear in DF2 from columns in DF1** which looks like this:

```
   KW
Shell Shocked
Tiger Blood 
Blue Suede Shoe
A Big Window
```

so that I would be left with...

```
   Words              Words1                Words2  
 Falling Down      Big Bang Theory        Hot Potato               
 Look Around       Mouse Trap
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  DF1 = DF1[~DF1['Words'].isin(DF2)]
  DF1 = DF1[~DF1['Words1'].isin(DF2)]
  DF1 = DF1[~DF1['Words2'].isin(DF2)]
```

This One did not actually filter anything (maybe I am doing this incorrectly).  I also tried:

```
 set_B = set(onlykw.itertuples(index=False))
 mask = [x not in set_B for x in A.itertuples(index=False)]
```

which returned nothing but 'True' (I found this on another SO post and I am not sure how it exactly works).  **Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `KW` the column name in DF2? If so, then you need

```
DF1 = DF1[~DF1['Words'].isin(DF2['KW'])]
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's it!  Always the simplest solution...Thank you :).  Will accept when SO lets me

Comment: @user3682157 Yeah, I've made this mistake myself enough times.